# When using Apache poi Duplicacy error in ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar and and poishadow-all.jar

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I am working on apache poi I add two .jar file 1. poishadow-all.jar (repacked all the apache poi jar) and ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar then I get bunch of duplicacy error

```
Include .jar present in src/libs
implementation files('libs\\poishadow-all.jar')
implementation files('libs\\ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar')
```

```
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.CTClientData found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.CTClientData$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STCF$Enum found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STObjectType found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STObjectType$Enum found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STObjectType$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank$Enum found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class com.microsoft.schemas.office.excel.STTrueFalseBlank$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Du

Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDouble$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTHeaderFooter found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTHeaderFooter$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayout found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayout$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayoutMode found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayoutMode$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayoutTarget found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Duplicate class org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLayoutTarget$Factory found in modules ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar (ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar) and poishadow-all.jar (poishadow-all.jar)
Du 
...............
```

Comment: The `poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar` is an excerpt of  classes from `ooxml-schemas-*.jar`. All classes from `poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar` also are contained in `ooxml-schemas-*.jar`. So if you wants using  `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` then ommit all classes of `poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar` in your fat `jar`.

Comment: sir how I can exclude poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar in Android

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this duplicacy error by marging these two .jar file into one

this is the great video for doing this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsndjGOc1w4